# Symbol already has basic type of CHARACTER

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran95

I have some code like the below in Fortran 90:

```
PROGRAM TICTACTOE
  IMPLICIT none
  character (len=1), DIMENSION(3,3) :: ticTac
  character :: winner

  SUBROUTINE CHKOVR(ticTac, over, winner)
    character (len=1), DIMENSION(3,3) :: ticTac
    character :: winner
    logical over

  END SUBROUTINE CHKOVR
END PROGRAM TICTACTOE
```

I am getting the errors:

```
tictactoe.f90:11:2:

   SUBROUTINE CHKOVR(ticTac, over, winner)
  1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
tictactoe.f90:12:47:

     character (len=1), DIMENSION(3,3) :: ticTac
                                               1
Error: Symbol ‘tictac’ at (1) already has basic type of CHARACTER
tictactoe.f90:13:23:

     character :: winner
                       1
Error: Symbol ‘winner’ at (1) already has basic type of CHARACTER
tictactoe.f90:16:5:
```

I am trying to convert some older fortran code to more modern fortran 90.

Admittedly I don't know the language very well at this point. In the old code this kind of stuff was working fine. Is the `ticTac` treated as a global variable here and I shouldn't be passing it to the subroutine? The old code did this, but I have a suspicion that what I have now is some kind of global variable.

Or is the problem something else?

Comment: You are missing a `contains` statement before defining the internal subroutine.  That would never have worked and the concept of internal procedure didn't exist until "recently".  Can you look carefully at the code which was working fine, as the subroutine won't be inside the program, perhaps.

Comment: @francescalus you're right, in the old program the `end` is before the subroutines. In my program I put the `end` at the very end. This is definitely a mistake. Once I switched that `end` to be before the subroutines everything works! Thanks! Feel free to post this as an answer if you'd like as that solved the issue.